# How to get json string from an array of object

Tags: php, arrays, json

Following code is giving an array with json objects. But I need json string of that array so that I can use json_decode later. How to do it?

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{   foreach($allGames as $game)
    {   if($game['desc']==$sortGames[$i])
        {   $text[$i]=array('Game_name'=>$game['desc'],'GameId'=>$game['gameId'],'order'=>$goalids,'length'=>$game['length']);
            break;
        }
    }
}
$json_string=json_encode($text);
```

the value of $json_string is as following:

```
[{"Game_name":"a","GameId":"1697","order":["11022","11021","11020","11024","11023"],"length":"2.08783938975344"},{"Game_name":"b","GameId":"1800","order":["12196","12197","12194","12195","12193","12198"],"length":"1.16970835124072"}]
```

Comment: what do u mean json string of array? in the result you get string already

Comment: The result is json array. json_decode is unable to decode it.

Comment: so the problem is you can't decode encoded string?

Comment: yes @bxN5 that is the problem

Comment: your json is correct http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/29f7ba1cdc6279ff27190fdab35b0032009c3675

Comment: you applied json_decode on `'[{"Game_name":"a","GameId":"1697","order":["11022","11021","11020","11024","11023"],"length":"2.08783938975344"},{"Game_name":"b","GameId":"1800","order":["12196","12197","12194","12195","12193","12198"],"length":"1.16970835124072"}]'`   but my text is: `[{"Game_name":"a","GameId":"1697","order":["11022","11021","11020","11024","11023"],"length":"2.08783938975344"},{"Game_name":"b","GameId":"1800","order":["12196","12197","12194","12195","12193","12198"],"length":"1.16970835124072"}]`

Comment: How to get this?

Comment: it work too http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f6f8d993a256666f15aca87c77ae21fb05aa3708

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f6f8d993a256666f15aca87c77ae21fb05aa3708  it is giving error

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{   foreach($allGames as $game)
    {   if($game['desc']==$sortGames[$i])
        {   $text[$i]=(array('Game_name'=>$game['desc'],'GameId'=>$game['gameId'],'order'=>json_decode($goalids),'length'=>$game['length']));
            break;
        }
    }
}
$json_string=json_encode($text);
```

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: Ok, it is fixing my problem but it is creating the order as null.

Comment: I made my code as:  `for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{   foreach($allGames as $game)
    {   if($game['desc']==$sortGames[$i])
        {   $text[$i]=(array('Game_name'=>$game['desc'],'GameId'=>$game['gameId'],'order'=>json_decode($goalids),'length'=>$game['length']));
            break;
        }
    }
}
$json_string=json_encode($text);
$test=json_decode($json_string,true);
var_dump($test);`

Comment: and the result is
`array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Game_name"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["GameId"]=>
    string(2) "57"
    ["order"]=>
    NULL
    ["length"]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
  [1]=>
  .... and so on..
}`

Comment: still null using htmlentities.. the error is : PHP Warning:  htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: i dont know more